# Seaborn line style from colum-name

Tags: python, seaborn

I have the dataframe:

```
      Blau_Loch  Blau_Scheibe  Rot_Loch  Rot_Scheibe
0        0.4190        0.4120     0.420       0.4110
1        0.4180        0.4130     0.421       0.4170
2        0.4200        0.4150     0.421       0.4140
3        0.4180        0.4100     0.422       0.4140
4        0.4190        0.4130     0.421       0.4130
```

How do I set the `style` parameter in `seaborn.relplot()` so that the plot for every column has a different style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't write many details about how you call the functions. You can set colors to `relplot` with `palette=` and markers with `markers=`. If you don't set them, you get default values. I'm not sure how to get a hollow circle using this setup; markers can be chosen from [this page](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/markers_api.html).

Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import pandas as pd
import seaborn

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Blau_Loch', 'Blau_Scheibe', 'Rot_Loch', 'Rot_Scheibe'],
                  data=[[0.4190, 0.4120, 0.420, 0.4110],
                        [0.4180, 0.4130, 0.421, 0.4170],
                        [0.4200, 0.4150, 0.421, 0.4140],
                        [0.4180, 0.4100, 0.422, 0.4140],
                        [0.4190, 0.4130, 0.421, 0.4130]])
seaborn.relplot(data=df, markers=['X', 'o', 'X', 'o'],
                palette=['steelblue', 'dodgerblue', 'crimson', 'tomato'])
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True)) # to display the x-axis as integers
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]